# Not able to login to localhost:8080/share and getting error for localhost:8080/alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have been following tutorials and documentation from alfresco for development and deployment but not able to login.

I have all in one sdk and it works fine if I run the ./run.sh file followed with login and other screens popping as normal follow. Now when I take alfresco.war(repo.war) and share.war to alfresco community and placed them on tomcat (/Applications/alfresco-community/tomcat/webapps) folder.

Now I run the alfresco using command ./alfresco start and able to see the login screen but not able to login where else I tried to open localhost:8080/alfresco and getting error as below.

[image: Localhost:8080/alfresco]

I have not changed any port or any config file and if I get back to original alfresco community files (alfresco and share wars file) then it opens both url followed with properly working.

***/**** UPDATE ****/***

**Postgresql is running on port 5433.**

**Alfresco.log are below: -**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#607cd510' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isSingleton(AbstractBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean.setBeanFactory(PropertyPathFactoryBean.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:980)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource'
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:277)
    ... 132 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource'
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck.<init>(DataSourceCheck.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 134 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck.<init>(DataSourceCheck.java:53)
    ... 139 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
    ... 142 more
```

**Postgresql.log is EMPTY.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your tomcat logs - why didn't the alfresco repo start?

Comment: Please show us the logs. PostgresSQL could not be started for many reasons (permissions, already used port, etc.)

Comment: @Akah I have updated my question. Also postgresql is running fine. It's just that if I replace only share.war then it works but when I replace both alfresco & share in alfresco community then it doesn't work.

Comment: Why have you configured Alfresco to use the `h2` database when you're running postgresql? (Error message shows it's trying to use h2)

Comment: Looks like your alfresco is trying to start on an h2 database, instead of a postgres one. Is your alfresco-global.properties ok ?

Comment: H2 database is to be used for the application so how to make it run now? Shall I stop postgresql ? or move someother files?

Comment: @Akah I saw alfresco-global.properties is targeting to H2 and we need postgresql. So what and where I need to make changes for it to work ?

Comment: I would say follow the doc from the bullet 10 : http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/postgresql-config.html

Comment: Thanks...  I will try that out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed, it was because of alfresco was looking for H2 database rather than postgresql (Thanks to @Akash & @Gagravarr). Also I have changed the version of alfresco community I was using (downgraded) and now its working fine.

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of localhost , can you try with IP address.

Comment: Tried with http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco but /alfresco is showing same error where else /share is loading page without letting me login.

Comment: Now I'm getting error "postgresql  could not be started" Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What is the port number on postgres? Postgres is running or not? If you alfresco.log + postgres would help us.

Comment: Postgresql port is 5433 and I have updated my question with logs.